# What linux app will read and write CART CHUNK information to WAV files?

Tags: command-line, command, wav

The system we play music on uses a header at the start of the file to save the file information ( Artist & Title ) to the file and then read it from there. I need to be able to put custom files in the system without having to manually edit the file with their software. These files are saved as .wav files.

I can see the data in the hexdump of the wave file and its in the first couple hundred lines. I've read that its the CART CHUNK info, but I can't seem to find any software that will read and write it in linux.

When I place a file in the playlist now, it shows a default [NAME] for the artist information but plays fine. Either using the cart chunk info or being able to just write the data to the file in the same spot should solve this.

Just stuck on how?

Comment: Your question seems to be unanswerable without knowing at least: - what kind of files (e.g. `.txt` text, `.jpeg` image, `.doc` word document, ...)? - what the `header data` stands for? - how to identify that files (e.g. all files in given folder?  all files of given name template? all files listed in a text file? a combination? ...)? _Please_ don't chat here. [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28240135/edit) instead

Comment: I have done that. Thanks.

Comment: What about your _custom piece of software_ converting `.mp3`s  to `.wav` format? Force **it** to write wanting header data to target files.

Comment: Then I'm back to doing it by hand which was the point of automating everything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found a repo that does what I'm wanting.

https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3

I'd like to be able to write better questions. What could I have said to make this easier to answer?

Answer (score 1):

Cart Chunk refers to the AES46-2002(s2008) standard found here:

http://www.aes.org/publications/standards/search.cfm?docID=41

You have to either be a member of AES to get the publication or purchase it for $50. 
Nobody has written a Cart Chunk metadata .wav writer or reader for Linux (that's publicly available.) For MacOS and Windows 10 Adobe Audition and Steinberg's Wavelab both write CartChunk info.

Comment: I will never support the CartChunk standard, as it's not an open standard. It's similar to ISO standards in that if you have loads of money it's open, and otherwise it's closed. I'm willing to read the chunk and spew out the binary content, but that's as far as it goes.